Optimize PostGIS query times
I am trying to optimize PostGIS query times. I currently have two tables in the db:
cj_geometry:
id:integer; metadataId:text; location:geometry; groundgeometry:geometry; bbox: geometry; cj_feature:jsonb
and metadata:
id:integer; metadataId:text; translate:real[]; scale:real[]; epsg:text;filename:text
What I am trying to do is to query mvt-tiles from the db on the fly. I use a function similar (this example was for a different table layout) like this to achieve this:
CREATE OR REPLACE
    FUNCTION function_zxy_query(z integer, x integer, y integer)
    RETURNS bytea AS $$
DECLARE
  mvt bytea;
BEGIN
  SELECT INTO mvt ST_AsMVT(tile, 'function_zxy_query', 4096, 'geom', 'id') FROM (
    SELECT
      ST_AsMVTGeom(
          ST_Transform(ST_CurveToLine("ground_geometry"), 3857),
          ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y),
          4096, 64, true) AS geom,
    "id",
    "cj_metadata_id",
    CASE WHEN z > 15 THEN '{"cityJson" : {"attributes":' || attributes::TEXT || ',"geometry":' ||  geometry::TEXT || '}' || '}' ELSE NULL END AS cityjson
    -- CASE WHEN z > 15 THEN '{"geometry":' ||  geometry::TEXT || '}' ELSE NULL END AS geometry
    -- "object_id",
    -- "type"
    FROM 
      cjdb.city_object
    WHERE 
      "ground_geometry" && ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y, margin => 0.015625), 3857)
  ) as tile
  WHERE geom IS NOT NULL;

  RETURN mvt;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE;

The problem I am having is that the queries take long. Too long. Around 3s for a query is just not accepable.
What can I do to make these queries as fast as possible? Indexing? Clustering? What do I need to do?
Any ideas?

to start with run explain on the query and add the output to your question, along with the actual query you are running.

hm, how would that help? if i run for example: select * from cj_geometry it  takes around 10s. running EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from cj_geometry only takes 0.09s with this return: Seq Scan on cj_geometry  (cost=0.00..26823.66 rows=171566 width=1141) (actual time=0.051..46.707 rows=171974 loops=1)or do i understandexplain` wrong?

That EXPLAIN plan gave more necessary information than you did, just by providing a row count. Imagine what it would tell about the actual query.

You might get some speed for free if you switch to language SQL instead of language PLpgSQL. If all you do is wrap a single query, choosing PLpgSQL just adds unnecessary overhead and prevents inlining. It would be easier for anyone looking at this question to discuss why the query performs the way it does and how to improve it if you attached table and index CREATE statements, along with the full output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS,VERBOSE) the_query_your_function_is_wrapping.

You probably need a gist index on ground_geometry, but to help you we need to have the result of an explain select function_zxy_query(z, x, y) where you replace x, y and z with actual values you see in real life example (which request took 3s ?). It will also help us if you tell us how much data is concerned (with a small zoom you probably have a lot of geometry on each tile) and what is their typical size.
